How to check whether a function template exists in C++?
Is there a way to check the existence of a function (of a specific signature) regardless of whether it is templated or not?
For example:
template <bool FLAG>
class A
{
public:
    template <bool FLAG_ = FLAG>
    std::enable_if_t<FLAG_, float> run(float a, float b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    float run(float a, float b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

Is it possible to write a generic trait, call it HasRun, that would determine whether a class has the method run() implemented? I.e.:
HasRun<A<true>>::value;  // <---- would return true
HasRun<A<false>>::value; // <---- would return false
HasRun<B>::value;        // <---- would return true

I'm aware of the following possible solution for non templated member functions:
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct HasRun : std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T>
struct HasRun<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::run)>::value>> : std::true_type
{
};

But this only works for B. Similarly I could adapt it to
template <typename T>
struct HasRun<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::template run<true>)>::value>> : std::true_type
{
};

but this would work for A<true>, would not work for B, and would "erroneously" work for A<false> (in the sense that A<false>::run() isn't implemented).

You can check if a function template (!) exists by testing to instantiate it. Without template parameters (deduced or not) there is no function.

Do you only want to check if it exists when accepting two floats btw?

No, simply if there is a function called run() implemented.

Ok, then, there exists no run<parameters...> until you've instantiated it. So you'd need to try an infinite amount of parameter combinations to see if any combination successfully instantiates it. How is this going to be used? There's probably a solution that doesn't require this check.

Imagine that I can miraculously tell you that run exists. I'm not telling you anyhing else about it. How would you use this information?

You've told us what you want to do, but not really why you want to do things this way (sounds like a XY problem). Maybe you could tell us a bit more about what problem you are trying to solve and then we can perhaps suggest alternative/better ways to do it..?

A more reasonable check in this case would be HasRun<T, Parameters...> which can check if T has a run overload taking the parameters you've specified. It doesn't work if the function template has template parameters that can't be deduced though.

"How to check whether a template function exists in C++?", HasRun<B>::value; // <---- would return true, but B doesn't have a template function...

@zhanginou I don't understand this. You've now accepted an answer that only works for specific run functions (accepting two floats and returning something that is convertible to float). You said "No" when I asked about it.

@TedLyngmo Yes, apologies, my bad. It turned out that a solution working for a specific signature was sufficient in my use case. I've edited the question accordingly.

@zhanginou No problem, but, the next time someone asks for a reality-check, pay attention :-)

As Bohdan Lakatosh has pointed out, the answer is quite straightforward using concepts. If you don't have access to concepts, but can use decltype, here's another approach using decltype, which will work for C++14 and up:
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <bool FLAG>
class A {
   public:
    template <bool FLAG_ = FLAG>
    std::enable_if_t<FLAG_, float> run(float a, float b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};

class B {
   public:
    float run(float a, float b) { return a + b; }
};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_run : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_run<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<T>().run(float{}, float{})), float>::value>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_run_v = has_run<T>::value;

int main() {
    std::cout << "has_run_v<B> = " << has_run_v<B> << '\n';
    std::cout << "has_run_v<A<true>> = " << has_run_v<A<true>> << '\n';
    std::cout << "has_run_v<A<false>> = " << has_run_v<A<false>> << '\n';
}


((T*)nullptr) -> std::declval<T>().

@Jarod42 Sure, why not?

Deferencing nullptr, even in non-evaluated context, seems bad...

That's actually how it was done before declval became a thing, and how it's done for other things, like offset_of in evaluated contexts.  But you already know that, right?

You can do it using concepts, if you are using C++20 or later.
As it was mentioned in comments, templates are not present in the code until you instantiate them. You can "instantiate" everything in the concept body.
Simple solution looks like this:
template <typename T>
concept runnable = requires(T inst, float x) { inst.run(x, x); };

template <typename T>
struct HasRun : std::false_type {};

template <runnable T>
struct HasRun<T> : std::true_type {};

int main() {
    // Using traits
    std::cout << "true = " << HasRun<A<true>>::value << '\n'
              << "false = " << HasRun<A<false>>::value << '\n'
              << "true = " << HasRun<B>::value << std::endl;

    // Using concepts directly
    std::cout << "true = " << runnable<A<true>> << '\n'
              << "false = " << runnable<A<false>> << '\n'
              << "true = " << runnable<B> << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Of course, if you create a concept, type trait feels redundant and you can use concept value as bool where it is needed.
Check discussion about similar case and concepts usage in it here
